# does same code can work on both android tablet and ipad perfectly?

Tags: android, ipad, cross-platform

Hello friends I am an android developer and right now i am working on sencha touch framework on android platform to develop an app which can run on multi platform e.g android tablets and ipads.

But i have question in my mind that if i create my app on android tablet emulator according to the android tablet need(means layout configuration),will the same app work on ipad? or i have to work on simulator to make it work on ipad? Please suggest me with ur views.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things works great for both of them. But there are some issues that you need to test on both the platforms e.g. `Video Player for playing local videos on SD card.`
Because, this generally is not a problem for iOS, but for android, you'll need your plugins. Also, from UI perspective, you must check on both the platforms. Since same CSS may or may not match. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Native (i.e. Activity/Window) code is not compatible between the two platforms.  If you develop using a web framework such as Phonegap, your differences will just be layout/CSS and plugin issues such as those mentioned by @Rajkiran.

You can also use commercial platforms such as [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) for abstraction of the hardware platform.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications) for more details.